# Individual Wordpress sites for students in a program--multisite or individual installs?

Tags: multisite, themes, installation

everyone. I teach in a journalism program at a university. The program has about 100-120 students. We want to be able to assign students a wordpress site when they enter the program, then let them use it to post their work as they move through the program (a portfolio).

We have been using wordpress in individual classes (no more than 20 students each), and for those I have always done individual installs for each student. However, I've been intrigued by possibly using multisite instead.

So, in this kind of situation, where I want to give students individual control of their websites (themes, etc.) and everything will be on the same domain, does it make more sense to do individual installs or to do a multisite and give each student a site?

I don't envision that there will be high traffic on any of these sites. We currently use GoDaddy for hosting, and I was thinking of upgrading to their Grow Plan.

Thanks in advance for any advice, pros/cons, etc.!

Comment: You may not receive a definitive answer as this is a somewhat subjective question. The biggest pro to individual installs is, it's easier to export the content so they can keep the website after they graduate. Another pro is one student can use a plugin that would conflict with a different plugin another student prefers, because the sites are separate and they won't conflict. The biggest pro to a MultiSite is, there's one site with one codebase to maintain.

Comment: Bear in mind, on multisite, only network admin (presumably yourself) can install themes and plugins. The admins of the individual child sites can choose whether or not to _activate_ these themes and plugins, but they cannot install new ones independently.